# Why does my public IP show a Bitcoin Node is running when it is set up over Tor?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, privacy, connection, tor

I've set up my node to run exclusively over TOR. But when I check https://bitnodes.earn.com/ and a few other sites with my public IP to check if a bitcoin node is accepting incoming connections, it comes back that it is.

How do I hide my public IP from showing that a full node is running ?

My `bitcoin.conf` settings are as follows:

- txindex=1
- server=1
- rpcport=8332
- listen=1
- proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
- bind = 127.0.0.1
- onlynet=onion

Comment: Sounds good to me at first sight. Maybe you had the node running without tor before and bitnodes is just showing cached info. Try https://canyouseeme.org/ or something like that.

Comment: I did have it running over both Tor and Clearnet before. And it looks like you were correct to say it was showing me cached info, because now my public IP gets no match anywhere as running a full node. Thanks !